# How to use Accessor when db seed?

Tags: postgresql, laravel, eloquent, postgis

I need to use the Accessor of an attribute of type postgres point.
In the db seeder, I just want to pass the lat long, while in the accessor, I am converting them to postgres geometry point format.

Here is the Accessor I am trying to use in the User model:

```
public function setSourceLatLongAttribute($value)
    {
        $latlong = explode(" ", $value);
        $latitude = $latlong[0];
        $longitude = $latlong[1];
        $this->attributes['source_lat_long'] = DB::raw("ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($latitude, $longitude), 4326)");
    }
```

and I just want to save the location in the seeder like this:

```
$users = [
        [
            'name' => 'Admin Istrator',
            'email' => 'admin@admin.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('1234'),
            'confirmation_code' => md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)),
            'confirmed' => true,
            'source_lat_long' => "31.9566 35.9457",
            'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
            'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
        ];
DB::table(config('access.users_table'))->insert($users);
```

What I expected is to have the Accessor called once I run the db seeder, but I got an error from the postgres db:

```
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[XX000]: Internal error: 7 ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
  HINT:  "31.9566 " <-- parse error at position 8 within geometry


  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[XX000]: Internal error: 7 ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
  HINT:  "31.9566 " <-- parse error at position 8 within geometry
```

So, the question is, can I use the Accessor to help me in this task of db seeding? or, how would I get the valid geometry to seed with?

Comment: Not an answer, but you need to swap the axis order to (X Y) or (long lat).

Comment: Also, I get the same error with a bogus `SELECT '31.9566 35.9457'::geometry` query, so it seems that `source_lat_long` is somehow trying to cast to a geometry.